# Groovy MissingMethodException when working with UTF-8

Tags: utf-8, groovy, character-encoding

Currently I have the following String:

```
String str = "Hello my name\n\t\t\t\tis Earl."
```

The problem is that the remote process that handles this String doesn't like the character encoding of the newline and tab characters. This remote process expects UTF-8.

So I wrote `convertSpecCharsToUtf8()` method:

```
private String convertSpecCharsToUtf8() {
    // "\n\t\t\t\t" as UTF-8
    char[] utf8 = new char[6]
    char[0] = '\\u000D'
    char[1] = '\\u000A'
    char[2] = char[3] = char[4] = char[5] = '\\u0009'

    new String(utf8)
}
```

And then changed my `str` String to:

```
String str = "Hello my name" + convertSpecCharsToUtf8() + "is Earl."
```

When I run:

```
println "Testing UTF8"
String str = "Hello my name" + utf8CRLFTabFormat() + "is Earl."
println str
```

I get:

```
Testing UTF8
Caught: groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method: static char.putAt() is applicable for argument types: (java.lang.Integer, java.lang.String) values: [0, \u000D]
groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method: static char.putAt() is applicable for argument types: (java.lang.Integer, java.lang.String) values: [0, \u000D]
    at com.me.myapp.convertSpecCharsToUtf8(Widget.groovy:133)
    at com.me.myapp.execute(Widget.groovy:111)
    at com.me.myapp$execute.call(Unknown Source)
    at com.me.myapp.main(Widget.groovy:37)
```

Why, and what's the solution here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a typo. Should be:

```
private String convertSpecCharsToUtf8() {
    // "\n\t\t\t\t" as UTF-8
    char[] utf8 = new char[6]
    utf8[0] = '\\u000D'.toCharacter()
    utf8[1] = '\\u000A'.toCharacter()
    utf8[2] = utf8[3] = utf8[4] = utf8[5] = '\\u0009'.toCharacter()

    new String(utf8)
}
```

Comment: Thanks @Opal (+1) but same exact exception; adding `toCharacter()` to each of the chars doesn't fix it...thoughts?

Comment: I dont' get any exception now.

Answer (score 1):

You can write a list with each character and use the `as` operator to coerce to `char[]`. You may also use `/str/` string declaration to avoid double escaping the backslash:

```
String convertSpecCharsToUtf8() {
  new String(  [/\u000D/, /\u000A/] + [/\u0009/] * 4  as char[]  )
}

def str = "Hello my name" + convertSpecCharsToUtf8() + "is Earl."

assert str == """Hello my name

        is Earl."""
```